# How to show google analytics statistic charts on certain page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, google-analytics, statistics

The scenario is there are few sites we manage and we want to create a portal that each site owner can login and see bunch of things regarding there site and that includes google analytics chart statistics/reports. Let's say the sites are site1.com, site2.com and site3.com and the portal would be a totally separate domain let's say siteportal.com. Each site owners will be registered and can login in the siteportal.com and they can view their google analytics chart based on which site they owned. If the owner of site1.com login in the portal then he can only view the analytics for his site whichs is site1.com. Same goes to other site owners. The analytics chart must be viewed on a page, not on the wordpress dashboard.

Is there a tool or plugin or anyway to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about google Data Studio raport per site and just embed each raport as iframe on "siteportal.com"?

Comment: @JacekSzymański Thanks for the tip man. Will try it out.